# large tables, slow performance

Tags: java, performance, swing, jtreetable

Given a `Java Swing` application that has 20 `JTreeTable` instances that contain data updating frequently. (each row updates 5 times/sec). These tables contain 50k rows each. Reducing the number of tables or the update rate is not an option.

This application suffers from both slowness (the Swing thread being cluttered) and also from intense GC activity caused by lots of short-lived temporary objects.

What would be some design advice in order to increase the performance?

Comment: So, you have 20 x 50,000 x 5 rows / second (5 million rows) updating every second?  How can anyone see the changes?  My advice would be to completely and absolutely separate the GUI model with the 5 million row updates per second from the GUI view.  The view would read the rows to be displayed only and display them once a second or so.

Comment: You could do a diff approach, load the values from your data source, do a diff between it and the data which is displayed, determine what's changed and only update those values which have changed